# Call with swipe in listview of contactlist

Tags: android, listview

I am am under development of an application which allows to make the contacts in a databse, and to show them in a listview.

At present I have it:

Database :

```
public class Contact {

    private int CTC_ID;
    private byte[]  CTC_IMAGE;
    public String CTC_NOM;
    public String CTC_NUMERO;

    public Contact(){
    }

    public Contact(int CTC_ID, byte[] CTC_IMAGE, String CTC_NOM, String CTC_NUMERO){
        this.CTC_ID = CTC_ID;
        this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NOM;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }



    public int getCTC_ID(){
        return CTC_ID;
    }
    public void setCTC_ID(int CTC_ID) {

        this.CTC_ID = CTC_ID;
    }

    public byte[] getCTC_IMAGE(){
        return CTC_IMAGE;
    }
    public void setCTC_IMAGE(byte[] CTC_IMAGE) {
        this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;
    }

    public String getCTC_NOM() {

        return CTC_NOM;
    }
    public void setCTC_NOM(String CTC_NOM) {
        this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;
    }

    public String getCTC_NUMERO() {

        return CTC_NUMERO;
    }
    public void setCTC_NUMERO(String CTC_NUMERO) {

        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "ID : "+CTC_ID+"\nimage : "+CTC_IMAGE+"\nnom : "+CTC_NOM+"\nnumero : "+CTC_NUMERO;
    }
}
```

databaseHelper :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kids_phone";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contact";
    private static final String TABLE_MESSAGE = "Message";
    private static final String TABLE_ASSOCIER = "Associer";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_CTC_ID = "CTC_ID";
    private static final String KEY_MES_ID = "MES_ID";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_ID = "ASS_ID";

    // Contact Table - column names
    public static final String KEY_CTC_IMAGE = "CTC_IMAGE";
    public static final String KEY_CTC_NOM = "CTC_NOM";
    public static final String KEY_CTC_NUMERO = "CTC_NUMERO";

    // Message Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_MES_TITRE = "MES_TITRE";
    private static final String KEY_MES_CONTENU = "MES_CONTENU";

    // Associer Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_ASS_IMG = "ASS_IMG";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_MES_ID = "ASS_MES_ID";
    private static final String KEY_ASS_CTC_ID = "ASS_CTC_ID";

    // Contact table Create Statements
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_CONTACT + " (" + KEY_CTC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_CTC_IMAGE
            + " BLOB," + KEY_CTC_NOM + " TEXT," + KEY_CTC_NUMERO + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Message table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGE
            + " (" + KEY_MES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_MES_TITRE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MES_CONTENU + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Associer table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ASSOCIER = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_ASSOCIER + " (" + KEY_ASS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ASS_IMG + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ASS_MES_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_ASS_CTC_ID + " INTEGER);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ASSOCIER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MESSAGE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ASSOCIER);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private static SQLiteDatabase bdd;
    static ArrayList<Contact> contactListe = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public void open() {
        //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
        SQLiteDatabase bdd = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
        bdd.close();
    }


    public long insertContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Création d'un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
        values.put(KEY_CTC_IMAGE, contact.getCTC_IMAGE());
        values.put(KEY_CTC_NOM, contact.getCTC_NOM());
        values.put(KEY_CTC_NUMERO, contact.getCTC_NUMERO());
        //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
        long CTC_ID = db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, values);

        return CTC_ID;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllContact() throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACT, new String[]{"CTC_ID _id", KEY_CTC_IMAGE, KEY_CTC_NUMERO}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public ArrayList<Contact> getListContact(){
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact list = new Contact();
                list.setCTC_ID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                list.setCTC_IMAGE(cursor.getBlob(1));
                list.setCTC_NOM(cursor.getString(2));
                list.setCTC_NUMERO(cursor.getString(3));
                contactList.add(list);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

The ContactAdapter :

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    // Constructor
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList.clear();
        this.contactList.addAll(contactList);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView name;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        final TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(contactList.get(position).getCTC_NUMERO());
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
        byte[] contactImage = contactList.get(position).getCTC_IMAGE();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contactImage, 0, contactImage.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return row;
    }
}
```

And my view :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lstViewContact;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                lstViewContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);

                displayContact();

}

    public void displayContact() {

        //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, dbHelper.fetchAllContactDetail());
        lstViewContact.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
}
```

At present that shows well the contacts,

I shall thus wish that when I swipe of the left to the right that call the number.

I have try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SwipeActionAdapter.SwipeActionListener {

    public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1234;
    protected SwipeActionAdapter mAdapter;
    private ListView lstViewContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                lstViewContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);

                displayContact();
}
    public void displayContact() {

        //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, dbHelper.getListContact());
        mAdapter = new SwipeActionAdapter(contactAdapter);
        lstViewContact.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasActions(int position, SwipeDirection direction) {
        if (direction.isLeft()) return true;
        if (direction.isRight()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDismiss(int position, SwipeDirection direction) {
        return direction == SwipeDirection.DIRECTION_NORMAL_LEFT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int[] positionList, SwipeDirection[] directionList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < positionList.length; i++) {
            SwipeDirection direction = directionList[i];
            int position = positionList[i];
            String dir = "";

            switch (direction) {
                case DIRECTION_FAR_LEFT:
                    dir = "Far left";
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_NORMAL_LEFT:
                    dir = "Left";
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_FAR_RIGHT:
                    dir = "Far right";
                    break;
                case DIRECTION_NORMAL_RIGHT:
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Test Dialog").setMessage("You swiped right").create().show();
                    dir = "Right";
                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    dir + " swipe Action triggered on " + mAdapter.getItem(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

But i Have this error in logcat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.picse.phone_kids, PID: 24155
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.View$OnTouchListener.onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
at com.wdullaer.swipeactionadapter.SwipeViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(SwipeViewGroup.java:174)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1961)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2394)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2809)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2355)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3593)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3710)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3601)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3593)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3601)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5939)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6029)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:915)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:710)
```

Thank you of the help that you go to bring me.

Comment: Could you check value of `hasActions` when it gets called?

Comment: there is issue with the library [check](https://github.com/wdullaer/SwipeActionAdapter/issues/45)

Answer (score 0):

You need special helper for this. Fortunately `RecyclerView` already have it.

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
[...]
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
    //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
   }
};

ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I make this :

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    ListView list;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private Context context;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx, ListView list) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        context = ctx;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public OnSwipeTouchListener() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void onSwipeRight(int pos) {
        Log.d("Swipe Right", String.valueOf(pos));

    }

    public void onSwipeLeft(int pos) {

        Log.d("Swipe left", String.valueOf(pos));
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        private int getPostion(MotionEvent e1) {
            return list.pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)
                    && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (distanceX > 0)
                    onSwipeRight(getPostion(e1));
                else
                    onSwipeLeft(getPostion(e1));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Main activity :

```
public void displayContact() {

    //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    final ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, dbHelper.getListContact());
    lstViewContact.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    lstViewContact.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this, lstViewContact));
}
```

But I want to when I swipe to right the app call to the number Which is in list view for example I have 2 contacts :

1 0231XxXxXx
2 0233XxXxXx

When I swipe to 2 it call the numer 0233XxXxXx and my list is dynamicaly.